# when is Snackbar isQueued () used? (How to queue the snackbar)

Tags: android, android-snackbar

If i call the snackbar multiple times in a row, only the last snackbar item is displayed.

e.g. with the codes below, only Item 3 would be shown. it seems that Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG is ignored (and set to zero?) for item 1 and 2.

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Item 1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Snackbar.make(view, "Item 2", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Snackbar.make(view, "Item 3", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

yet in the [google documents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#isShownOrQueued()), I see that it is possible to queue the messages.

> ```
> public boolean isShownOrQueued ()
>
> Returns whether this Snackbar is currently being shown,
> or is queued to be shown next.
> ```

so how do we actually queue the snackbar?

Comment: Just a note, this method was added to the most recent Support Library (23.1.0) http://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/23.1.0/changes/android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.html

Comment: Did anybody find out how `isShownOrQueued()` can be used?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a partial snippet that solves your problem, although it might not 
be the correct way to go about things:

```
//using a queue to pass string to the snackbar
Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
myQueue.offer("item 1");
myQueue.offer("item 2");
myQueue.offer("item 3");
displaysnack(myQueue, view);

public void displaysnack(final Queue dQueue, final View view){
    Snackbar.make(view, (String)dQueue.poll(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
            switch (event) {
                case Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked the action", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                //once the timeout expires, display the next one in the queue.
                case Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing: "+ (dQueue.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (dQueue.size()>0){displaysnack(dQueue, view);}
                    break;
                case Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_CONSECUTIVE:
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Multiple Shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

I also needed to implement a queue of snackbars but did not find ready solution. So I decided to implement it on my own. You can try it https://github.com/AntonyGolovin/FluentSnackbar.

Just call `important()` on Builder and it will be added to the queue.

Comment: Nice. This is how it should have worked from the start.

Answer (score 4):

I also implemented my own, probably not the slickest but suited my needs. Its in C# for **Xamarin** though.

```
public class SnackbarManager : Snackbar.Callback
{
    List<Snackbar> snackbarsWaiting;
    List<Snackbar> snackbarsHolding;
    public SnackbarManager()
    {
        snackbarsWaiting = new List<Snackbar>();
        snackbarsHolding = new List<Snackbar>();
    }

    public void AddToQueue(Snackbar snackbar)
    {
        if (snackbar.Duration == Snackbar.LengthIndefinite) snackbar.SetDuration(Snackbar.LengthLong);
        snackbar.SetCallback(this);
        if (snackbarsWaiting.Count > 0 && snackbarsWaiting[0].IsShown) snackbarsHolding.Add(snackbar);
        else snackbarsWaiting.Add(snackbar);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        if (snackbarsWaiting.Count > 0 && !snackbarsWaiting[0].IsShown)
            snackbarsWaiting[0].Show();
    }

    public override void OnDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int evt)
    {
        base.OnDismissed(snackbar, evt);
        snackbarsWaiting.Remove(snackbar);
        if (snackbarsHolding.Count > 0)
        {
            snackbarsWaiting.AddRange(snackbarsHolding);
            snackbarsHolding.Clear();
        }
        if (snackbarsWaiting.Count > 0) snackbarsWaiting[0].Show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem too, this is my solution.

```
static List<Snackbar> snackBarList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void mySnackBar(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, String s,boolean queued) {

    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

    if (queued) {

//if true set onDismiss CallBack

        snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback()
        {          
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar currentSnackbar, int event) {
                super.onDismissed(currentSnackbar, event);

//first remove current snackBar in List, then if List not empty show the first one

                snackBarList.remove(currentSnackbar);
                if (snackBarList.size() > 0) 
                    snackBarList.get(0).show();

            }

        });

//add (set callback) snackBar to List

        snackBarList.add(snackbar);

//the beginning

        if (snackBarList.size() == 1)
            snackBarList.get(0).show();

    } else snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a library that do just that. It also includes progressBar. Try it out https://github.com/tingyik90/snackprogressbar